# Regular expression to form JSON from arp -a result

Tags: regex, bash, shell, command-line, arp

I've got a arp -a result like so:

```
Albacore (192.168.1.1) at a5:5d:a1:ec:e3:52 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
Beaufort (192.168.1.109) at 3B:EA:D2:2D:7F:06 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
```

and I need to form JSON from it, that looks like this:

```
[
 {
  "ip":"192.168.1.1",
  "mac":"a5:5d:a1:ec:e3:52",
  "hostname":"Albacore"
 },
 {
  "ip":"192.168.1.109",
  "mac":"3B:EA:D2:2D:7F:06",
  "hostname":"Beaufort"
 }
]
```

I know, that this regular expression could find hostname

```
^\S*
```

this could be used to find ips

```
((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
```

and this to mac addresses

```
([0-9a-f]{1,2}[\.:-]){5}([0-9a-f]{1,2})
```

They are probably not best, but they should get the job done for my usecase.

Anyway, I can't figure out how to put it all together and form JSON.

Thank you for all your advices.

Comment: If you can parse what you want, then your issue is not regular expression, you can simply use a python script to dump the JSON form you want

Comment: research the `printf` program for `bash` or the function in `awk`. This can all be done in one `awk` script.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your regex are not working using python regex so I changed them a bit, here is an example using python:

```
import re
import json

lines = ["Albacore (192.168.1.1) at a5:5d:a1:ec:e3:52 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]",
"Beaufort (192.168.1.109) at 3B:EA:D2:2D:7F:06 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]"]

json_file = open('json.txt', 'w')
json_file.write("{\n")
for line in lines:
    dump = {}
    dump['hostname']  = re.findall(r'^(.*?)\s', line)[0]
    dump['mac'] = re.findall(ur'(?:[0-9a-fA-F]:?){12}', line)[0]
    dump['ip']  = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', line)[0]
    json.dump(dump, json_file)
    json_file.write(",\n")
json_file.write("}")
json_file.close()
```

output in `json.txt`:

```
{
{"ip": "192.168.1.1", "mac": "a5:5d:a1:ec:e3:52", "hostname": "Albacore"},
{"ip": "192.168.1.109", "mac": "3B:EA:D2:2D:7F:06", "hostname": "Beaufort"},
}
```

You can also edit the JSON data display if you want, for more about it: https://appdividend.com/2019/04/15/how-to-convert-python-dictionary-to-json-tutorial-with-example/

Answer (score 0):

Read input line by line via a [`while`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html#EX25) loop and `read`:

```sh
while read line || [[ -n $line ]]; do
    ...
done
```

The check ensures we don't act on bad input.

Capture components into variables via [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html):

```sh
ip="$(echo "$line" | sed 's/<capture pattern>/\n/')"
```

Output lines of text with captures substituted where you want them via `printf` and [parameter expansion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html):

```sh
printf "%s\n" "\"ip\":\"${ip}\","
```

This should be enough to put a working script together. Additionally, if the output from arp is reliably well-defined, then you can avoid the regexes and simply split the lines on a delimiter (here, whitespace), and use indices and variable expansion to accomplish the same.

Split the line on whitespace into an array via [`read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html):

```sh
read -ra arr <<< "$line"
```

Access [`array`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html) elements via:

```sh
${arr[index]}
```

The ip capture will require some [string manipulation](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) to remove the parentheses. Remove them via:

```sh
ip=${arr[1]#(}
ip=${ip%)}
```

Put it all together and you have something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

## we'll insert commas between items before inserting the next item
## rather than at the end so that we don't add a trailing comma.
## we'll need this flag to know if we're at the first insertion,
## where we won't insert a comma.

first=1
printf "%s\n" "["
while read line || [[ -n $line ]]; do
    if [ $first -eq 0 ]; then
        printf "%s\n" ","
    else
        first=0
    fi

    read -ra arr <<< "$line"

    ip=${arr[1]#(}
    ip=${ip%)}

    printf "%s\n" "  {"
    printf "%s\n" "    \"ip\":\"${ip}\","
    printf "%s\n" "    \"mac\":\"${arr[3]}\","
    printf "%s\n" "    \"hostname\":\"${arr[0]}\""
    printf "%s" "  }"
done
printf "\n%s\n" "]"
```

I am not familiar with arp but if this file were named, say, `arp-to-json`, then you would presumably use it via:

```sh
arp -a | arp-to-json
```

You can do a quick check that the json is well formatted using `jq`:

```sh
arp -a | arp-to-json | jq --indent 4
```

The expected output should match what you indicated precisely.